# Game with Google Analytics failing to build due to linker errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I'm doing an unity project that is an AR game played with mobile devices. It uses vuforia for the AR part. Recently I added Google Analytics for Unity (the googleanalyticsv3.unitypackage from the developer site). After that, when I try to build on iOS, I get a lot of "Apple Mach-O Linker" errors (Android still builds just fine). I was able to remove some of them by adding the necessary frameworks, but I still have around 50 of them. I added libsqlite3.dylib, libz.dylib, SystemConfiguration.framework and CoreData.framework. I then also added security.framework which also seemed to reduce errors on the build. I then went back a few commits on the project, before I added the Analytics, and it was still building fine on the same Unity and Xcode versions.

Pasted below are the errors I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char*, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::uflow()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::mutex::~mutex()", referenced from:
      StateHolder::~StateHolder() in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(Tracker.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(double&)", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      l12810 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18582 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18597 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::cerr", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12905 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::tellg()", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18597 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18636 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      l18629 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18636 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)", referenced from:
      l18582 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18597 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      l18582 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18597 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::__next_prime(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      l18338 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18347 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18357 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sync()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(double)", referenced from:
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::init(void*)", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12858 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
      l12804 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12809 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)", referenced from:
      l12806 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12809 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::seekg(std::__1::fpos<__mbstate_t>)", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(float&)", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18582 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      l12805 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l17392 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18583 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18584 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18585 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18592 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18593 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18582 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12858 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18612 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18626 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18627 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18628 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18630 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12858 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18612 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18626 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18627 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18628 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      l12808 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12858 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18582 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(unsigned int&)", referenced from:
      l12809 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios()", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12858 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18612 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18626 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18627 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18628 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      l12808 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12809 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12810 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12811 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12846 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12848 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18582 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18591 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18730 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::mutex::lock()", referenced from:
      StateHolder::QCAR_onUpdate(QCAR::State&) in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::setStateBufferSize(unsigned int) in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::updateCurrentState() in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::getCurrentState() in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::hasStateBeenSet() in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      l12809 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18594 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l18649 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::get()", referenced from:
      l12806 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12809 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12811 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      l18629 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      l12922 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char*, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::mutex::unlock()", referenced from:
      StateHolder::QCAR_onUpdate(QCAR::State&) in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::setStateBufferSize(unsigned int) in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::updateCurrentState() in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::getCurrentState() in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
      StateHolder::hasStateBeenSet() in libQCARUnityPlayer.a(StateHolder.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      l12809 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12812 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
      l12858 in libVuforia.a(libVuforia.a-armv7-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have seen this issue a lot on the net but it seems to be mostly fixed by just adding the correct frameworks, but I should have them all, at least all I have seen on the net. I also tried with AdSupport.framework, but it had no effect, so I removed since it could apparently make the iOS review fail (and I have no need for that kind of tracking). I have also build this same project 4 times (cleanly, in a new folder each time), added the frameworks, removing them and adding them again. I also removed Vuforia and Google Analytics from the project and re added them, and then built a new version but no change. I would be hugely thankful if someone can help me fix this!

[Here is picture of the frameworks and libraries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4oFI.png)

Unity version is 4.6.7f1, Xcode is 6.4. I downloaded latest versions of both Analytics and Vuforia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got there on my own. After viewing git commits for long enough and trying enough stuff, I discovered that Google Analytics had replaced PostProcessBuildPlayer (in Assets/Editor/) when I added it to the project, which meant that Vuforia was not building itself correctly. I added the Vuforia version back and renamed the Analytics version PostProcessBuildPlayer_GA, and added the correct frameworks when building. After that it built beautifully.